# Как воспользоваться классом из другого проекта в пределах одного решения? c++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

У меня есть три проекта. Два из них решают одну и ту же задачу, только один написан в процедурном стиле, другой в объектно-ориентированном (задание на курсовую). И третий проект с формами.

К формам я подключал первые два проекта. Подключал другой проект через ПКМ по проекту, свойства, c/c++, общие, дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов ...

Каждый из проектов (ООП и процедурный) на консоли запускается и работает как надо, но с формами работает только процедурный проект. Когда я подключаю ООП проект, то выдаются ошибки: lnk2028, lnk2019, lnk1120.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Включить файл заголовка библиотеки в вашу программу?

Comment: Ну как бы я в курсе этого. Я же написал, один проект подключается к формам и все отлично, но ООП проект даже не хочет подключаться, он банально не собирается. Не собирается при подключении к формам, сам по себе он работает.